# Getting table from web page using Beautiful Soup and Pandas

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Running with Python 3.6.1 the code

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# url_addr = "https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/ac/ido/oeip/taf/mclsstc/mcls1.htm"
url_addr = "https://www.cefconnect.com/closed-end-funds-daily-pricing"
html_text = requests.get(url_addr).content
bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html_text)
tables = bs_obj.findAll('table')
dfs = list()
for table in tables:
    df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
    dfs.append(df)
    print(df)
```

gets only column headings but not the actual data, with output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Ticker, Fund Name, Strategy, ClosingPrice, PriceChange, NAV, Premium/Discount, DistributionRate, DistributionRate on NAV, 1 Yr Rtnon NAV]
Index: []
```

It works for the url_addr that is commented out.

Comment: are you getting any output from tables before read_html?  What does one of their outputs look like?  If there is output there, my guess is that it is failing on read_html.

Comment: I checked the website and it looks like you are trying to access a table that is dynamically generated. Hence `bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(html_text)`  is not fully rendered and the table is infact empty. You should use an api that completely renders the webpage and pass it into BeatifulSoup(). Check out scraperapi or proxycrawl.

Answer (score 1):

The second URL populates the table with Javascript. If you use `wget` or look in the network tab in Google Chrome, you'll see this is the table as it is originally sent (ie, this is what beautiful soup is seeing):

```
        <div id="data-container" class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">                    
                <table class="cefconnect-table-1 daily-pricing table table-striped table-condensed" id="daily-pricing" width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="ticker">Ticker</th>
                            <th class="fund-name">Fund Name</th>
                            <th class="strategy">Strategy</th>
                            <th class="closing-price">Closing<br />Price</th>
                            <th class="price-change">Price<br />Change</th>
                            <th class="nav">NAV</th>
                            <th class="premium-discount">Premium/<br />Discount</th>
                            <th class="distribution-rate">Distribution<br />Rate<sup>&dagger;</sup></th>
                            <th class="distribution-rate-on-nav">Distribution<br />Rate on NAV</th>
                            <th class="return-on-nav">1 Yr Rtn<br />on NAV</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And then some Javascript populates the table. You have two options from here, either use a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) (like PhantomJS, Selenium, there are plenty of options that are relatively easy to use) and run the Javascript before parsing or try to figure out how to access the API that the page uses to add the data.

Another option, that I always like to mention, is to contact the owner of the site and work out an arrangement to obtain the data in a more straightforward way.